# Use str.extract to extract multiple matches in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [
            "name=John, name=Billy",
            "name=Jeff",
            "name=Taylor",
        ]
    }
)

df.select(
    [
        pl.col("a").str.extract(r"name=(\w+)", 1),
    ]
)
```

I'll get a Series with `John, Jeff, Taylor`. I'm wondering if there's a way to `extract_all`(?) and also get `Billy`? I realize this changes the dimensionality of the resulting series but was just wondering if this method is available somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is a [`str.extract_all`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.internals.expr.ExprStringNameSpace.extract_all.html) method.

```py
df.select(
    [
        pl.col("a")
        .str.extract_all(r"name=\w+")
        .explode()
        .str.extract(r"name=(\w+)")
        .alias('names')
    ]
)
```

```
shape: (4, 1)
┌────────┐
│ names  │
│ ---    │
│ str    │
╞════════╡
│ John   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Billy  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Jeff   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Taylor │
└────────┘
```

Comment: And the docs are updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> df.select([
        pl.col('a').str.split(', ').explode()
                   .str.extract('name=(\w+)')
    ])

shape: (4, 1)
┌────────┐
│ a      │
│ ---    │
│ str    │
╞════════╡
│ John   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Billy  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Jeff   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Taylor │
└────────┘
```

Comment: I can't accept this as it does not solve the general case -- only the special case given above. I need to be able to extract more complex expressions that are not so regularly split.